# Confusion regarding Gibbs phenomenon

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-series

I learned that the partial sum of the fourier series at a jump discontinuity always overshoots the value of the original function by about 9% and this percentage does not die out as we increase the terms of the partial sum.

On the other hand, by Dirichlet's theorem we have that the fourier series converge to the average of the jump discontinuity.

I feel that these two statements are contradictory. The first stating that the value of the fourier series at a discontunity will always have a fixed overshoot for all partial sums. And the other saying that the fourier series gets closer and closer to the average of the discontunity which implies that the overshoot is decreasing and approaches zero as we increase the terms of the partial sum.

So can someone clear my confusion?

Comment: (if the function is piecewise continuous) the point at which there is "an overshoot of 9%" goes closer and closer to the discontinuity point. and because of the symmetry, at the point of discontinuity the is no overshoot and the Fourier series converges to the mean value of the left and right limits. hence, for every fixed point, the series ends up by converging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gibb's phenomenon doesn't affect the point *at* the jump discontinuity. It says that, if you go a bit to either side of the jump discontinuty (in a certain proportion to $\frac{1}n$, where $n$ is the number of terms of the Fourier series that you've summed), you will observe that the function overshoots the target by about $9\%$ of the size of the jump discontinuity.

The classic example is illustrated as follows, where I have plotted the 20th partial Fourier series of $\frac{\pi}4\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ where $\operatorname{sgn}$ is the sign function:
[image]

In blue is the Fourier series and in red is the sign function. Note that, just to the right of $0$, where the jump discontinuity is, the Fourier series exceeds intended value and similarly to the left. However, right at the jump discontinuity, the function is $0$, which is the average of either side. One observes that adding more terms causes the place where the overshoot happens to get closer to $0$, but that this issue is orthogonal to the issue of what exactly the value at $0$ converges to.

Comment: Now can we say that in the limit as $n$ gets infinite,the upper and lower bumps/overshoots near the point of discontinuity gets closer and closer to each other until they cancel out so that the value of the series becomes the average at that point(in our case zero)?

Comment: @OmarNagib Not really; the places where it overshoots are always separated from each other by a finite distance (since one is left of the discontinuity and the other right). You can see that the value at the center is *already* zero - we don't need anything to cancel. What happens to the bumps is that they get more and more compressed near zero and, in the pointwise limit, don't end up affecting anything, since for any point that isn't zero, the bump is eventually well closer to zero than that point, and at zero, the value was already at $0$.